# Accessing API resource by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, api

say this `api.football-data.org/v1/competitions` contains the following

```
{
    "_links": {
      "teams": {
        "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/444/teams"
      }
    },
    "id": 444,
    "caption": "Campeonato Brasileiro da Série A",
    "league": "BSA"
  },
{
    "_links": {
      "teams": {
        "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/445/teams"
      }
    },
    "id": 445,
    "caption": "Premier League 2017/18",
    "league": "PL"
  }
```

what is the best way to access the specific team? I do it this way, it works but I think it's not very neat.

HTML

```
Choose Team: <select id="team">
                <option value="444">Premier League</option>
                <option value="445">Campeonato Brasileiro</option>
            </select>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#team").change(function(){
    var id = $("#team").val();
    getTeam(id);

});

function getTeam(id){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/'+id+'/team',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var team= '';
                $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                    team+= '<tr><td>' + v.name+ '</td></tr>';

                });
                $("#team").html(team);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not very neat? I think it's perfectly acceptable

Comment: Are you looking for more control on the client to get competition with teams included? If so then graphql might work better for you than rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, but you can use the URL returned from API. I think this API was created according to Richardson Maturity Model (more information here: https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).
The api-football is on level 3 - with hypermedia controls - because the API tell us what we can do next (get teams, get players...)

So, it's can brings some advantages for your application: if the api-football changes some URL, your application won't break.

You can change your solution, if you want:

```js
        var apiKey = '7b35712f29da4dc58a538320e57c12cc';

        $(function () {
            getCompetitions();
            $('#competitions').change(function () {
                var urlTeam = $("#competitions").find("option:selected").attr('data-href');
                getTeam(urlTeam);
            });
        })

        function getCompetitions() {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/',
                headers: {
                    "X-Auth-Token":apiKey
                },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                        $('#competitions').append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-href="' + v._links.teams.href + '">' + v.caption + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        function getTeam(url)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    "X-Auth-Token":apiKey
                },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var team = '';
                    $.each(data.teams, function (k, v) {
                        team += '<tr><td>' + v.name + '</td></tr>';
                    });
                    $("#teams").html(team);
                }
            });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> Choose Competition: </label>
<select id="competitions">
  <option>Select...</option>
</select> <br />
<label>Teams </label>
<table id="teams">
</table>
```